# How to rename the columns inside nested column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, data-cleaning, azure-synapse

I have a column product inside which there is a nested column called Color. I want to remove the {} from the column color.

I don't want to flatten the column and rename it. I directly want to rename the column or drop the column.

```
|-- product: struct (nullable = true) 
| |-- {Color}: string (nullable = true)
```

I have tried dropping it but it doesn't work. I don't want to create a new struct as I have many more nested columns and they are too much.

```
|-- product: struct (nullable = true)
| |-- {Color}: string (nullable = true)#
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and what code you have used to rename?

Comment: see [`withField`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html#pyspark-sql-column-withfield) to add/update struct fields.

Answer (score 2):

Try with **`.withField`** to update the field name without flattening.

Then use **`.dropFields`** to `drop nested columns` from struct.

**`Example:`**

```
#sample json
json = '{"product":{"{Color}":"a"}}'
df = spark.read.json( sc.parallelize([json]))

#create Color column by using `.withField` and copy the `{Color}`data
#use .dropFields to drop struct columns
df1= df.withColumn("product", df['product'].withField('Color',col('product.`{Color}`'))).\
withColumn("product", col("product").dropFields("`{Color}`"))
df1.printSchema()
df1.show(10,False)

#root
# |-- product: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- Color: string (nullable = true)
#
#+-------+
#|product|
#+-------+
#|{a}      |
#+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can use `withColumn` to rename the nested column. The following is a code that you can use. I have a dataframe with following schema (same as yours):

```
df.printSchema()
```

[image]

- Now using `withColumn` as shown in the below image, you can change the name of your nested column color:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, struct

df.withColumn("product", struct(col("product.{Color}").alias("Color"))).printSchema()
```

[image]